# How to find features of a word variant (using SimpleNLG)?

Tags: java, nlp, nlg, simplenlg

My idea is to, given a word variant and a base form from another word, reproduce the features from the word variant in the base form.

I've been able to produce a word variant from a base form given a set of features, my problem lies on gathering these feature from the original word variant.

So far, my workaround is to use Stanford Parser and filter the POS tags of the word variant, thus recovering some (but not most) features. Then using SimpleNLG I'm able to create the new word variant.

Any other tools or libraries for Java, that provide these functionalities, are also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleNLG is as the name suggests... simple. You may want to take a look at libraries handling language at a more semantic level. Of notable examples there is OpenCCG (http://openccg.sourceforge.net/). This is going to be a bit of work though.